# Custom date format in Controller method parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to set a custom date format for a controller method?

I mean: I'd like to user `yyyyMMddHHmm` format for date used in query string and in my controller I have this method:

```
public Object getResultsByDate(DateTime date){
    // some code...
}
```

I'd like to set my custom format at method level via an annotation, something like:

```
public Object getResultsByDate([CustomFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")] DateTime date)
```

Is there something similar?

Comment: why not creating your own parameter-attribute? :)

Comment: You will need to create you ow custom `ModelBinder` to use a format like that.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger because I'm focused on the main problem and I'd like not to waste my time reinventing the wheel... ;)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok... I'll do... thanks

Comment: @MatthiasBurger I'm not angry at all, I was just answering your question. Thanks for your suggestion. Have a nice day! ;)